# Linuxデスクトップ環境で、しばらく操作しないと画面が真っ黒になるが、このタイミングで任意のスクリプトを実行したい

Tags: linux, c, raspberry-pi, x11

Linuxデスクトップ環境を使用しています。しばらくキーボードやマウスを操作しないでいると、画面が真っ黒になり、キーボードやマウスを操作すると復帰します。このタイミングをトリガにして、自分の用意したスクリプトを走らせることは可能でしょうか？

具体的にやりたいことは、Raspberry Piに接続された専用液晶モニタで、消灯時にはバックライトをオフにし、点灯時にはバックライトを元に戻したいのです。専用液晶モニタなので、HDMI等の汎用ディスプレイポートを使用しておらず、バックライトを制御するには、そのためのコマンドを実行する必要があります。

省電力イベントが発生したときに、バックライトの制御を行いたいと思っています。バックライトのオンオフを制御するコマンドはありますが、イベントでスクリプトを実行させる方法が分かりません。

環境は、Raspbery Pi, 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie, Xfce4 です。

Comment: 個人的な好みでXfce4にしましたが、Raspbian標準のLXDEでも同様なので、X Windowの一般的な挙動ではないかという気がします。また、画面を消すのを完全に無効化して、代わりに、同様な機能を実装したスクリーンセーバーを自作することはできないか、とも考えています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自分で調査した結果を報告します。

まず、スクリーンセーバーを無効にします。

```
$ xset s off
```

DPMS (Display Power Management Signaling) の設定を行い、消灯までの時間を設定します。

```
$ xset dpms 60 60 60
```

ディスプレイの状態を取得します。

```
$ xset q|grep Monitor
  Monitor is On
```

この表示結果をポーリングすれば、ディスプレイがオフになったことを知ることができます。

ただし、`xset q`コマンドは、多くの情報を取得するため、無駄が多いので、知りたい情報に限定して取得するプログラムをCで書きます。

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/extensions/dpms.h>

int main()
{
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    if (d) {
        int dummy;
        if (DPMSQueryExtension(d, &dummy, &dummy)) {
            if (DPMSCapable(d)) {
                CARD16 state;
                BOOL onoff;
                DPMSInfo(d, &state, &onoff);
                if (onoff) {
                    switch (state) {
                    case DPMSModeOn:      puts("on");      break;
                    case DPMSModeStandby: puts("standby"); break;
                    case DPMSModeSuspend: puts("suspend"); break;
                    case DPMSModeOff:     puts("off");     break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

コンパイルする際は、`X11`と`Xext`をリンクします。

```
$ cc monitor.c -o monitor -lX11 -lXext
```

私がやりたかったことは、Raspberry Pi専用モニタのバックライト制御なので、`state`の値が`DPMSModeOn`か、そうでないかに応じて、バックライト制御を行えば、目的を実現できそうです。

なお、X11とスクリーンセーバーとパワーマネジメントに関することなので、Xfceは関係ありません。

---

#### 参考情報

DPMSに関して
https://wiki.archlinuxjp.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

ディスプレイの状態を得る
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819255/how-to-check-if-linux-console-screensaver-has-blanked-screen

Answer (score 4):

raspbianは分かりませんが、大抵のXのデスクトップ環境ではD-Busでコントロール出来ます。
`xdg-screensaver`コマンドの内部でも`dbus-send`コマンドを使っていますし、それが標準に則った方法なのだと思います。
D-Busはよく分かっていませんが以下の様な感じでよさそうです。

```sh
# 状態の確認
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive

# シグナルのモニタ
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',path=/ScreenSaver,member=ActiveChanged"
```

シグナルのモニタ、Python板

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GLib

def changed_hdl(arg):
    print(arg)


DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
loop = GLib.MainLoop()
session = dbus.SessionBus()
saver = session.get_object('org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver', '/ScreenSaver')
saver.connect_to_signal('ActiveChanged', changed_hdl)
loop.run()
```